# Add gapps to custom rom?

Tags: android-source, rom

I am really new to rom development, however i managed to build a custom rom for galaxy nexus. I obviously dont have gapps.

I am wondering how can i incorporate gapps in the build without having to flash a .zip file?

The apps are not open source and they are prebuilt apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the APK files for the Google apps that you would like to include. Copy each one under the directory /system/app/ and chmod 644 (change permissions to rwrr). Recompile your ROM and flash it as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

goto https://github.com/opengapps and in opengapps repo follow the instruction.. there will be a common makefile to initiate the build then you have to add its path  to your romname_device.mk

Answer (score 0):

You can use `micro g` project for using google services in custom ROMs. For example in `Replicant` ROM microg is used. Micro g has multiple tools such as location services , appstore and etc.